# Group by: ORA-00937: not a single-group group function

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, having

Why is this query not working properly?

```
SELECT e.* 
FROM enrolled e 
FULL OUTER JOIN student s ON e.studentid = s.sid 
WHERE ((e.quarter = 'Fall') OR (e.quarter = 'Spring')) 
GROUP BY e.studentid 
HAVING count(e.studentid) == 1;
```

Error that happens:

> ORA-00937: not a single-group group function 00937. 00000 - "not a single-group group function"   *Cause: *Action: Error at Line: 1 Column: 8

Thanks,

Comment: it is giving me a error saying "missing expression"

Comment: You're using `==`? Are you sure? Not just a single one? Can you tell us the error message from sql server? By the way I would do the part in the where-statement with the `IN` operator ... `WHERE e.quarter IN ('Fall','Spring')`

Comment: I am doing what I posted in the question.  Here is what it says: "ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
00937. 00000 -  "not a single-group group function"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 1 Column: 8"

Answer (score 4):

As Rene said, you can't select columns which aren't in the group by clause.

If you want to select these columns but only for `studentid`s that have `count(*) = 2` for some critria you can do it like this:

```
select *
from
(SELECT e.*, count(*) over (partition by e.studentid)  cnt
FROM enrolled e 
FULL OUTER JOIN student s ON e.studentid = s.sid 
WHERE ((e.quarter = 'Fall') OR (e.quarter = 'Spring')) 
)
where cnt = 2
```

Or

```
SELECT e.*, count(*) over (partition by e.studentid)  cnt
FROM enrolled e 
FULL OUTER JOIN student s ON e.studentid = s.sid 
WHERE ((e.quarter = 'Fall') OR (e.quarter = 'Spring')) 
  AND (select count(*) from enrolled i where i.studentid = e.studentid) = 2
```

Anyway, you can't do `==` only `=`

Answer (score 1):

When you use "group by" you can only select the columns that are used in the "group by".

You are selecting e.*. change that to e.studentid.

And its `having count(*) = 1`. Not `having count(*) ==1`.